# How to make such animation in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I have the basics of AE but I don't know everything, I would like to make an animation like the one in the link, with phone, if someone can tell me where to find such tutorial then that would be great. The animation of the phone is my main problem, it looks like a 3d model in sketch style. https://www.planradar.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/iPad_EN-1.mp4

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need vector paths for drawing the tablet/phone it the style you have shown. (like in this video https://youtu.be/zSlXOIsfjLY?t=123)
Next you just need to put that all in 3D via camera settings and each layer as an 3D object and work this out step by step.
I think you should find many examples on youtube for what you are looking for.